# Tilde floats above superscript instead of above letter

Tags: equations, tilde

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\Tilde{B_{k}^{ij}} = f(B^{i})_{k} + (1 - \lambda) f(B^{j})_{k} \\
\Tilde{y^{ij}} = \lambda y^{i} + (1 - \lambda) y^{j}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

This is my current equation. Unfortunately, the tilde is not directly placed on the B, but instead floats above the supercript. How to fix this?

[image: Tilde example]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  The problem is in the input.  The tilde should be placed above only the letter it modifies: `\Tilde{b}_{k}...` or `\Tilde{y}^{ij}`.

Comment: Note that `\Tilde` and `\tilde` are exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\Tilde{B}_{k}^{ij} = f(B^{i})_{k} + (1 - \lambda) f(B^{j})_{k} \\
\Tilde{y}^{ij} = \lambda y^{i} + (1 - \lambda) y^{j}
\end{split}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Observe, where are `}` : \Tilde{B}_{k}^{ij} instead of `\Tilde{B_{k}^{ij}}`.

BTW, it will be helpful, if you would extend your code fragment to complete small document.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome and the nice answer! That's exactly what I was looking for. I will keep in mind having a MWE.